# Notify webapp that the image has been successfully captured from android hybrid app

Tags: android, callback, hybrid-mobile-app

I have below query:

**Scenario** We have developed an android hybrid application, where our web application hosted on remote server is opened inside the webview container of Android.

**Requirement** To capture image from camera and attach with the form.

**Limitations** Android cannot call methods (callback) on remote javascript. The web application, being a single page HTML5 and jQuery application, cannot be reloaded/navigated.

**Present Implementation** We are able to open camera by capturing the url navigation event of android webview (navigation triggered on ‘attach’ button click to a dummy url for website).
But still no way to notify the webApp that the image has been successfully captured/uploaded on server.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to poll server at regular intervals and check. Since u cannot call remote js.

Other option not preferred, is to reload webview(refresh current page in browser history) once u are done with image uploading in background from native.

Comment: We are doing the same ie polling the server